# Application performance degraded ~10x when migrated from 2008R2/VS2010 to 2012R2/VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I have an application that performs certain action in 150 ms on Windows 2008 R2 Standard. It performs the same action in 1100 ms on Windows 2012 R2 Standard.

The 2008 has Visual Studio 2010 .NET4 C#.
The 2012 has Visual Studio 2013 and is also .NET4 C#.

Both are compiled in 32-bits mode.

Haven't had time yet to migrate to .NET 4.5.1 nor to compile in 64-bits mode.

The Visual Studio's profiler reports: "DA0014: (Average)Pages/sec = 3,731.56; An extremely high rate of paging active memory to disk is occurring. Your application may be memory-bound." But there is PLENTY of memory.

The action involves the consumption of a web service in IIS on local machine.

Anyone can help?